# Can the SASS minifier remove duplicate styles?

Tags: css, sass

I know that the css rules are fairly complex; however, couldn't the following css be fairly simply reduced in a number of ways by the optimizer? And if so, is there an option for it in the rails-sass gem?

```css
span {
    background: red;
    color: green;
}

.test2 {
    background: red;
    color: green;
}

span {
    background: green;
    color: inherit;
}

.test2 {
    background: inherit !important;
    color: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    color: inherit;
}
```

**Additional Context:**

To help clarify, I would propose the following as well...

Source:

```css
span {
    background: red;
}
span {
    background: orange;
    color: green;
}
span {
    background: yellow;
}
span {
    background: blue;
    color: green;
}
```

And, I would want a compiler to generate the following:

```css
span {
    background: blue;
    color: green;
}
```

I know there are redundant styles, but this happens many times when continually revising stylesheets, and I want to eliminate the dead code.

Comment: You could run the outputted CSS through [CSSTidy](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/) or the like.

Comment: Did you find a way to do it? What is the advised way to achieve this as of 2019?

Answer (score 6):

I think that I may have found a way to at least find the duplicate styles in both css and sass/less templates:

The open source csscss gem http://zmoazeni.github.io/csscss/

It appears to be able to detect duplicates, although I am having to monkey patch around the bootstrap-sass gem's css not being in the same folder as my css assets.

From the documentation, you can run:

```
$ csscss -v path/to/styles.css
```

or

```
$ csscss -v path/to/styles.css.scss
```

Comment: "although I am having to monkey patch around the bootstrap-sass gem's css not being in the same folder as my css assets." - Please file an issue on [github](https://github.com/zmoazeni/csscss/issues). I'd like to know what you're trying and what is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of, SASS will only format your code differently but not optimize it for you http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style

Expanding on Whymarrh's comment, CSSTidy has a command line utility that could be integrated in a build process or similar, http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/csstidy

Comment: The problem with csstidy is that it hasn't been maintained in years, so I don't believe that it will support the newer media selectors, and multiple background properties needed for gradients and responsive designs.

Comment: That's right but, you can also set a flag to ignore unknown syntaxis, so at least that will be left untouched, I ran some tests yesterday, against a set of 10 exported CSS files and the result was kind of disappointing, in the best case, we had around 1% of gain in compression, keep in mind that our company is very anal when it comes down to performance, so things like #ffffff (instead of #fff) are not acceptable, your mileage may vary, I'd recommend you to take it for a test drive at least :)

Comment: If you have node.js installed there is [csso](https://github.com/css/csso), which looks like it is being actively maintained. The manual explains what optimizations it will do.