# How to override SASS style without duplicating CSS

Tags: css, sass

I'm pretty new to SASS and I'm currently using a library written in SASS.
I would like to override not only variables from this library but also styles for a few bits. How can I override this style without duplicating CSS for that specific class ?

To be clear, let's say I have this class in my library which I import in my main.scss:

```
.twitter-foo {
    float: none;
}
```

Now in my own file:

```
.twitter-foo {
    float: a lot more;
}
```

Then my output is:

```
.twitter-foo {
    float: none; // overriden!
}
.twitter-foo {
    float: a lot more;
}
```

Well it works but it's dirty and I hate duplicating code, not mentioning the slightly longer page load. In case I would like to redefine `.twitter-foo` from my library, what can I do to avoid the bloated CSS ?

**EDIT:** I'm not talking about a middleware (minifier?) between SASS and CSS output but just SASS really.

Comment: Did you find a solution? As of 2019, could you advise the best way to achieve this using SCSS/SASS?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is be more specific, meaning add more selectors so you can target .twitter-foo in different ways. Try giving your body tag a page id or your main element is what I usually do. So...

```
<body id="page1">
</body>
```

then in the scss you can:

```
#page1 .twitter-foo {
   float:none;
}
```

OR

to override or not override add !important to the end of the style for example:

```
.twitter-foo {
    float:none !important;
 }
```

hope that helps.

Edit

As discussed [Can the SASS minifier remove duplicate styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161595/can-the-sass-minifier-remove-duplicate-styles)

you may be able to compile your sass then run it through a css tidy which will remove duplicate classes and stuff or try out that ruby gem in the answers http://zmoazeni.github.io/csscss/.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply! :) That helps for the quick fix, but I'll still get my useless `.twitter-foo` class from the library which I'll never use then I don't want it. I would like to redefine it! Is there a way?

Comment: what do you mean redefine it?

Comment: I use that library because there are a lot of nice features, but in some cases, let's say that bloody -> `.twitter-foo`, I just want it to, if I rewrite after the first definition, then make the whole class redefined. No souvenirs! Is that possible?

Comment: No, Sass doesn't do this out of the box. You may be able to find a sass minification tool which will remove duplicates and redundant classes. Why not just remove that class out of the library is you do want the clutter.

Comment: The reason why I don't do that is, as I pull the library from bower, I would break any change made to it from the repository that I might find useful for just a few classes I wanted to change. It's unbelievable SASS developers didn't think about overriding a class in SASS transparently for the CSS output, it's like they thought there would be no SASS library ever!